# How can I make the tkinter label(selected in the listbox) dynamic?

Tags: python, tkinter, dynamic, listbox, label

```py
newWindow = Toplevel(app)
newWindow.geometry("400x400+580+190")
Label(newWindow, text="choose the food").pack()
choice = Listbox(newWindow)
choice.pack()
food_f = open("food.txt")
for line in food_f:
    f = {}
    (f['food'], f['unit'], f['kcal'], f['standard']) = line.split(";")
    choice.insert(END, f['food'])
t = StringVar()
t.set(choice.curselection())
Label(newWindow,textvariable=t).pack()
```

I want the label to print out in real time what is selected in the list box.
But above code can't.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a binding on the virtual event `<<ListboxSelect>>`, and from within the bound function you can get the selected item and update the label using the `configure` method.

For example, given a listbox named `listbox` and a label named `label`, you can update the label like this when the selection changes:

```
def update_label(event):
    curselection = listbox.curselection()
    if curselection:
        data = listbox.get(curselection[0])
        label.configure(text=data)
    else:
        label.configure(text="")

listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", update_label)
```